# opap betting site data url

Tags: json, api

it seems i'm the only one in Googlesphere willing to write this program (in Python) that handles data from OPAP betting site and i'm missing the data (odds, game hours etc). The site provides no API but i was told to monitor the calls from the site's json link and job is well done. The closest i found is  http://praktoreio.pamestoixima.gr/web/services/rs/iFlexBetting/retail/games/15104/0.json?shortTourn=true&startDrawNumber=686&endDrawNumber=686&sportId=s-441&marketIds=0&marketIds=0A&marketIds=1&marketIds=69&marketIds=68&marketIds=20&marketIds=21&marketIds=8&locale=en&brandId=defaultBrand&channelId=0 Still zero, I'd appreciate the right one